# Search for Phone Number Pattern in a file

Tags: c++, regex

I need help with my C++ code.

I want to search a file and read it line by line and if the parent of a phone number matches it must print that line to another file.

I am able to match a string but not sure : How to match a format/pattern of a phone number Phone numbers can be different. I just want to follow the format of phone number match.

Example of Number can be xx-xxx-xxxx

This is my code take a look

```
// reading a text file

         if (mywritingfile.is_open())
         {

                  //Getting data line from file.
              while ( getline (myfile,line) )
            {

                 if (Match the Pattren from the line)//Need Help Here.
                 {   
                     //Printing the Mached line Content Of the source File to the destination the File.
                     //Output Every line that it fetches
                     cout << line << endl;
                     mywritingfile << line << endl;
                     matches++;   
                 }
            }
         }
```

Comment: Maybe you could use `std::regex` or `boost::regex` to check the pattern.

Comment: @g-makulik Can you direct me how can i use that in my If condition there i mean the syntax.

Comment: Is that precise pattern the **only** phone number pattern you will accept? If so the regular expression is quite easy: `\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}`. While I've never used regex's in C++, you can start here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/

Comment: It takes more preparation and coding than in a single line, have a look at the [`std::regex` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) to get more information and usage examples.

Comment: What exactly are you having problems with? Give us details. Shorten your code down to the parts that are relevant to the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is short example how to use regex (C++11).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
  std::regex r("[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{3}-[[:digit:]]{4}");

  std::string s1("12-311-4321");
  std::string s2("112-311-4321");

  if (std::regex_match(s1, r)) {
    std::cout << "ok" << std::endl;
  } else {
    std::cout << "not ok" << std::endl;
  }

  if (std::regex_match(s2, r)) {
    std::cout << "ok" << std::endl;
  } else {
    std::cout << "not ok" << std::endl;
  }

    return 0;
}
```

All you need to do is check every line using `std::regex_match` function.

Comment: Add my simple regex in the comment above to this code, and I think you've got it.

Comment: @kmort, I added valid regular expression to code. I tested it superficially, please check it on your own.

Comment: And for anyone wondering about the disparity between `\d` and `[[:digit:]]`, they both work. The first is shorthand, the second is POSIX character classes. I prefer shorter (less typing) but some prefer the full thing spelled out (easier to read). http://cpprocks.com/wp-content/uploads/c++11-regex-cheatsheet.pdf